# Matching ContentType as a string, get invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: django

Using the model from django updown:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name="updown_votes")
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    key = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    score = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=_SCORE_TYPE_CHOICES)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, related_name="updown_votes")
    ip_address = models.IPAddressField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
    date_changed = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
```

I am trying to get a user's rating with:

```
    user_rating = Vote.objects.get(user=user, content_type='post', object_id=id)
```

But, I get the error:

ValueError at /post/30/  invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'post'

So, it doesn't like the string. But, user_rating.content_type is 'post'.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I match for content type of 'post'?

Appreciate the help! :)

Edit:

url for post:

```
    url(r'^post/(?P<id>\w+)/$', 'single_post', name='single_post'),
```

full view:

```
def single_post(request, id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    all_comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post).order_by('timestamp')
    total_rating = post.rating_likes - post.rating_dislikes
    comment_count = Comment.objects.filter(post=post).count()
    comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    user = request.user

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user_rating = Vote.objects.get(user=user, content_type='post', object_id=id)
        print user_rating.content_type
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your logic on the get query. Are you going to have another `object_id` that is the same with a different `content_type`?

Comment: You should also post your URL pattern and view.

Comment: @Brandon yes, the plan is to have comment votes as well, which could have the same object_id - so I thought the best way to split them was content_type

Comment: Hmm. Have you seen: https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments ?

Comment: Yep, I tried a few of the comments apps out there, but I always needed to add to them, so thought I better do my own. Might need to relook if there is no solution to this...

Comment: I work with the ContentTypes framework all the time, there are several ways to get the content type instance... can you please post your url and view?

Comment: Thanks, I have added the url for the single_post and the related view. Most of the rest is in https://github.com/weluse/django-updown

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62998/discussion-between-pete-drennan-and-brandon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Post model is expecting id to be an integer, so change your URL pattern to:

```
url(r'^post/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'single_post', name='single_post'),
```

You'll need to filter the `Vote` model by a `ContentType` model instance, not by the string 'vote':

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

def single_post(request, id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    . . .
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(vote)

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user_rating = Vote.objects.get(user=user, content_type=content_type,
            object_id=id)
    . . .
```

When you look up an object by foreign key reference, Django expects you to provide an object to do the comparison, unless you specify a property, like `__id`, etc.